# Iterating over all tick marks except the last one

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a bunch of rects based on my tick marks. However, I'd like not to draw a rect for the last tick mark. How do I do that? I've tried slicing `hoursg.selectAll('g.tick')`, but that didn't work.

**EDIT:** Updated code and added SVG, see comments.

```
    // draw axis below data
    hoursg = svg.append('g').classed('axis', true).classed('hours', true).classed('labeled', true).attr("transform", "translate(0.5," + yaxisHeight + ")").call(hoursAxis).style("opacity", axisOpacity);

    // Need the pixel dimensions between each tick e.g. three hours.
    hoursTickSpacing = weekscale(moment(start).add(3, 'hours').toDate()) - weekscale(start.toDate());

    // add day/night shading by adding elements to the dom for every tickmark in the hours axis.
    var hourTicks = hoursg.selectAll('g.tick');

    hourTicks.filter(':not(:last-child)').insert('rect', ':first-child').attr('class', function (d, i) {
            var hours;
            hours = d.getHours();
            if (hours < 6 || hours >= 18) {
                return 'nighttime';
            } else {
                return 'daytime';
            }
        }).attr('x', 0).attr('width', hoursTickSpacing).attr('height', 8);
```

Here's the created SVG object:

```
<g class="axis hours labeled" transform="translate(0.5,100)" style="opacity: 0.6;"><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(12.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(25,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(37.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(50,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(62.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(75,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(87.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(100,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(112.50000000000001,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(125,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(137.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(150,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(162.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(175,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(187.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(200,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(212.49999999999997,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(225.00000000000003,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(237.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(250,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(262.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(275,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(287.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(300,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(312.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(325,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(337.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(350,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(362.50000000000006,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(375,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(387.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(400,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(412.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(424.99999999999994,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(437.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(450.00000000000006,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(462.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(475,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(487.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(500,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(512.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(525,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(537.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(550,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(562.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(575,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(587.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(600,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(612.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(625,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(637.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(650,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(662.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="daytime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(675,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(687.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(700,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g><path class="domain" d="M0,8V0H700V8"></path></g>
```

It's the `<g class="tick" transform="translate(700,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><rect class="nighttime" x="0" width="12.5" height="8"></rect><line y2="8" x2="0"></line><text dy=".71em" y="14" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text></g>` object that's problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [d3.selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter):

```
hoursg.selectAll('g.tick')
  .filter(isNotLastTick)
  .insert('rect')
  //...
```

Where `isNotLastTick` is a function that returns a truthy value if the given datum does not represent the last tick.

Here's an example of `filter`:

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4];

var p = d3
  .selectAll('.p')
  .data(data);

p.enter()
  .append('p')
    .attr('class', 'p')
    .text(function(d) { return d })

p.filter(function(d, i) { return i === 0 })
  .attr('style', 'color: red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here's an example of `filter` without a data join:

```js
var p = d3.select('div').selectAll('p');

p.filter(':not(:last-child)')
  .attr('style', 'color: red')
```

```html
<div>
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your method. To do that I would need to find the length of `hoursg.selectAll('g.tick')` so my filter could be `i != tick_length` or something similar, right? How would I find the length?

Comment: Are you using a data join? In that case, it's the length of your data array. If you're simply selecting existing elements, I think you can use the string `":last-child"` as the argument to `filter` instead of a function. I haven't actually tried that before.

Comment: I'm still quite new to d3 so I'm not exactly sure. But I don't think I'm using a data join as I'm not using the `join()` method anywhere in my script.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This selects the last child - what if I want to select all other objects than the last child?

Comment: Just a matter of using a different CSS selector - `':not(:last-child)'`. I've updated the example.

Comment: Am I missing some little detail? Seems like you've been kind enough to provide me all the info I need to fix this.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your SVG element?

Comment: I thought I had written a comment mentioning that I had posted the SVG element in the original post. Sorry about that. See my edited question.